# Does Pattern.compile cache?

Tags: java, regex

It is likely an implementation detail, but for the Oracle and IBM JDKs at least is the compiled pattern cached or do we as application developers need to perform the caching of compiled patterns ourselves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe the results are cached and there's no evidence of such behaviour in the [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/regex/Pattern.java) or the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). It would (of course) be relatively trivial to implement such a cache yourself, but I would be interested in a use case in which such caching is beneficial.

Re. the comment below and [String.split()](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html), there's a different approach in that the code takes a distinct path for trivial 1 or 2 char patterns vs more complex regexps. But it still doesn't appear to cache.

Comment: To avoid parsing regular expression every time? If I recall correctly, in JDK 7 String.split() does caching of Pattern for simple cases.

Comment: I understand it would avoid parsing the regexp each time, but my experience of regexps is that a) I've not often been concerned with performance b) if I have, it's rarely the compilation stage which has concerned me. YMMV

Comment: Thanks that's pretty lousy that it does provide some sort of optimization within the JDK code itself.  It just does a new Pattern() Thanks for the links.

Comment: @helpermethod What's the relevance of the Python regex engine to someone coding in Java?

Comment: I like the way it's implemented in Java.  Most of the time, developers wouldn't want Java to cache regexes.  If it did, you could end up with a leak or at least some wasted memory.  If you want to implement it yourself you can and it's trivial to do so.  Brian Agnew, you are interested in a use case where this is beneficial.  I have this use case myself.  I allow users to create their own regexes (and I validate them of  course).  The users use these regexes to test millions of event strings per second.  It would be a colossal disaster not to pre-compile and cache these.

Answer (score 13):

As far as I know from looking at the code (JDK 6) it doesn't do caching but once constructed, Pattern object could be cached on application side and shared among multiple threads. Standard pattern seems to be to assign it to final static variable:

```
private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(",");
```

Answer (score 6):

According to **[Joshua_Bloch] Effective_Java**:

Some object creations are much more expensive than others. If you’re going
to need such an “expensive object” repeatedly, it may be advisable to cache it for
reuse. Unfortunately, it’s not always obvious when you’re creating such an
object. Suppose you want to write a method to determine whether a string is a
valid Roman numeral. Here’s the easiest way to do this using a regular
expression:

```
// Performance can be greatly improved!
static boolean isRomanNumeral(String s) {
return s.matches("^(?=.)M*(C[MD]|D?C{0,3})"
+ "(X[CL]|L?X{0,3})(I[XV]|V?I{0,3})$");
}
```

The problem with this implementation is that it relies on the
String.matches method. While String.matches is the easiest way to
check if a string matches a regular expression, it’s not suitable for repeated
use in performance-critical situations. The problem is that it internally creates
a Pattern instance for the regular expression and uses it only once, after
which it becomes eligible for garbage collection. Creating a Pattern instance
is expensive because it requires compiling the regular expression into a finite
state machine.
To improve the performance, explicitly compile the regular expression into a
Pattern instance (which is immutable) as part of class initialization, cache it,
and reuse the same instance for every invocation of the isRomanNumeral
method:

```
// Reusing expensive object for improved performance
public class RomanNumerals {
private static final Pattern ROMAN = Pattern.compile(
"^(?=.)M*(C[MD]|D?C{0,3})"
+ "(X[CL]|L?X{0,3})(I[XV]|V?I{0,3})$");
static boolean isRomanNumeral(String s) {
return ROMAN.matcher(s).matches();
}}
```

The improved version of isRomanNumeral provides significant
performance gains if invoked frequently. On my machine, the original version
takes 1.1 μs on an 8-character input string, while the improved version takes
0.17 μs, which is 6.5 times faster

Answer (score 5):

I've created a class **CachedPattern** that can cache **Pattern** objects.
If you run the **main** method you'll see that Java's **Pattern** objects are in fact different instances, which also consumes memory.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert;

public class CachedPattern {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("abc");
    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("abc");
    Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("abc");
    Pattern p4 = Pattern.compile("abc");
    Pattern p5 = Pattern.compile("abc");

    Pattern x1 =  CachedPattern.compile("abc");
    Pattern x2 =  CachedPattern.compile("abc");
    Pattern x3 =  CachedPattern.compile("abc");
    Pattern x4 =  CachedPattern.compile("abc");
    Pattern x5 =  CachedPattern.compile("abc");
    // are cached objects the same ? YES!
    Assert.isTrue(x1.equals(x2));
    Assert.isTrue(x1.equals(x3));
    Assert.isTrue(x1.equals(x4));
    Assert.isTrue(x1.equals(x5));
    // are non-cached objects the same ? NO!
    Assert.isTrue(p1.equals(p2)); //AssertionFailedException
}

 private static HashMap<String, Pattern> cached = new HashMap<>();

 /**
  * This value must be unique, to make sure user won't use this inside "regex" variable,
  * so that objects without flags would be returned
  * For example if UNIQUE_HASH would be empty:
  *     compile(pattern = "abc1")
  *          VS.
  *     compile(pattern = "abc", flag = 1)
  * This would give same keys "abc1" and "abc1"
  */
 private static final String UNIQUE_HASH = "(())[]+@#$%^@!@#$%*";

 public static Pattern compile(String regex){
     if(cached.containsKey(regex)){
         return cached.get(regex);
     }
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
     cached.put(regex, p);
     return p;
 }
 public static Pattern compile(String regex, int flags){
     String uniqueKey = regex + UNIQUE_HASH + flags;
     if(cached.containsKey(uniqueKey)){
         return cached.get(uniqueKey);
     }
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
     cached.put(uniqueKey, p);
     return p;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't. If you have performance sensitive areas, you might want to hold your pattern objects as member variables.

Clojure does this more or less automatically when you have a regex in a function though.